# Add perfix to route in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, action-filter

I have a filter attribute that checks if the URL path contains a certain prefix that the user manually enters. For example:

```
http://..../prefix/area/controller/action/id
```

Now when a user accesses a different "controller/action" I want to be able to add this same prefix to the new route so that the filter will detect the prefix again. So if the user clicks on a button that redirects them to:

```
http://..../area2/controller2/action2/id2
```

I want to append to the route and make it:

```
http://..../prefix/area2/controller2/action2/id2
```

Now when the filter attribute checks the URL, the prefix will be maintained.

I was thinking of maybe using another Filter Attribute, but I'm really not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just create a new area and move the relevant controllers there?

Comment: Isn't that just adding some characters into each route? Why use a filter when you can just create a route with that text in? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnH There is already an area section. I am trying to avoid adding another parameter in each URL action.

Comment: @levelnis That's exactly what I've done. There is another route with the prefix. But once the route with prefix is accessed, it should be maintained instead of switching back to the route without the prefix. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you have controllers that will be accessible outside of this prefix?  Also, what is your current routing configuration?

Comment: @JohnH, No regardless of whether or not there is a prefix, the same controller is accessed. As for the current routing configuration, I'm not sure what you're asking for specifically.